# django-rest-framework token authentication fails on production

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework for my authentication system, using the webservices provided by [Djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser).

In my local Django server, I can retrieve the user from [/auth/me/](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/views.py#L243) without any problem. But in production I recieve 401 (Unauthorized) error.

Do I need some special setting server-side to make it work properly? Thank you.

Comment: Why not try to search for logs from your nginx and then gunicorn configurations?

Comment: Hi. Have you found the solution to this problem??